# Calculation of determinant using its properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The task is to calculate the following determinant by using the properties of a determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
        n^2 & (n+1)^2 & (n+2)^2 \\
        (n+1)^2 & (n+2)^2 & (n+3)^2 \\
        (n+2)^2 & (n+3)^2 & (n+4)^2 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$
**Hint:** The result is $-8$.

Comment: what are you looking for?

Comment: @Johan The way to calculate it.

Comment: If I had to do this, I would begin with the $2\times 2$ leading principal minor, which gives the other corners by change of variable, then appy Dodgson's [method of condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation).

Comment: Wouldt it be dependent on n?

Comment: @Johan No, it isn't. I have checked it on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: ah maybe it cancels out..

Comment: Use the formula for the 3x3 determinant...I know the algebra is unpleasant, but at least you'll be able to calculate *any* variable determinant. All these tricks do, is teach you how to handle rare exceptions. For instance, the Dodgson's usually ok to use, but it becomes inefficient if there are zeros in the matrix.

Comment: @Zach466920 Using algebra will give you a solution, provided you are cautious of course, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @JimVerr then the Op should specify if that's the case, because he says "using obviously the properties of a determinant"...

Comment: this problem has several answers at the link in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Expanding all the terms isn't so bad in this example.

**ROWS-TRANSFORMATIONS**
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4\\
n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4&n^2+6n+9\\
n^2+4n+4&n^2+6n+9&n^2+8n+16
\end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4\\
n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4&n^2+6n+9\\
2n+3&2n+5&2n+7
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4\\
2n+1&2n+3&2n+5\\
2n+3&2n+5&2n+7
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4\\
2n+1&2n+3&2n+5\\
2&2&2
\end{pmatrix}$$
**COLUMN-TRANSFORMATIONS**
$$\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&n^2+4n+4\\
2n+1&2n+3&2n+5\\
2&2&2
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&n^2+2n+1&2n+3\\
2n+1&2n+3&2\\
2&2&0
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&2n+1&2n+3\\
2n+1&2&2\\
2&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
n^2&2n+1&2\\
2n+1&2&0\\
2&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
So $\mathrm{det}(A)=-8$.

Comment: I calculated it using row operations as in your example more or less but I was hoping if I could get a more neat answer by adding a column to another or something like that, but your way might be the only one in the end. Thanks for the effort.